# How to read nested innerHtml and add background to parent?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, tampermonkey

I'm having trouble working through a webpage - I need to find some known `innerHtml` in a table, and affect the parent tag of the tag that contains the innerHtml. Afraid I have little to no JavaScript game...

The HTML looks like the below:

```
<table> <tbody>
    <tr class="header">
        <td>
            <table> <tbody>
                <tr class="header">
                    <td> <u> January </u> </td>
                    <td>foo</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody> </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="header">
        <td>
            <table> <tbody>
                <tr class="header">
                    <td> <u> February </u> </td>
                    <td>bar</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody> </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody> </table>
```

I'm trying to FIND "January" and add background color to the parent , here's my code so far:

```
var thetr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
for (j = 0; j < thetr.length; j++) {
    var theTd1 = thetr[j].getElementsByTagName('td');
    for (k = 0; k < theTd1.length; k++) {
        var theTd2 = theTd1[l].getElementsByTagName('td');
        for (m = 0; m < theTd2.length; k++) {
            if (theTd2[j].innerHtml == "January") {
                thetr[j].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 195, 195)";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Not getting anything... if I add an alert to show me the `innerHtml` that it's reading of each level I just get 'undefined'. How wrong is my method? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things:

1. Always check the browser console for errors.  There you would have seen things like:

   > `l` is not defined
2. Use `querySelectorAll()` (or use jQuery) to find nodes.  You'll save yourself a ton of grief.
3. Except when creating brand new nodes, using `innerHtml` in a Tampermonkey script is almost always a mistake and very brittle even if it works for a while.  Your script, or the page, will break with the slightest change.
4. If the page is AJAX-driven, static methods like that that will fail, irregardless.

For **a static page**, this demo shows Vanilla.js for that row highlight:

```js
var headerCells = document.querySelectorAll ("tr.header > td > u");
headerCells.forEach (uNode => {
    if (/January/i.test (uNode.textContent) ) {
        uNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "lime";
    }
} );
```

```html
<table> <tbody>
    <tr class="header">
        <td>
            <table> <tbody>
                <tr class="header">
                    <td> <u>January</u> </td>
                    <td>foo</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody> </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="header">
        <td>
            <table> <tbody>
                <tr class="header">
                    <td> <u>February</u> </td>
                    <td>bar</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody> </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody> </table>
```

---

Or, **in jQuery,** the code is as simple as:

```
$("tr.header > td > u:contains(January)").closest ("tr").css ("background", "lime");
```

---

For either a static page or **an AJAX-driven page**, here is a complete Tampermonkey script that works:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Highlight January
// @match    *://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directives are needed to restore the proper sandbox.
/* global $, waitForKeyElements */

waitForKeyElements ("tr.header > td > u:contains(January)", justLimen);

function justLimen (jNode) {
    jNode.closest ("tr").css ("background", "lime");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, for the thorough explanation, and such concise code. I've used your full TM script, it works beautifully, and I'm learning a bit about AJAX, which does seem to be at play...